# Adding new files to Makefile.am

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash, altcoin-development, compiling

I need some help with adding files to the code base by adding them to the autotools build system. Other [posts](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53957/how-to-add-own-cpp-files-to-makefile) that try to answer the same question haven't helped me. I am experimenting with Bitcoin's codebase and I am trying to add new files to the codebase. I am trying to add a static library in the src/Makefile.am by adding these lines:

```
LIBGLYPH=libglyph.a

libglyph_a_SOURCES = \
glyph/glp.c \
  glyph/glp_utils.c \
  glyph/glp_rand.c \
  glyph/glp_rand_openssl_aes.c \
  glyph/FFT/FFT_1024_65537.c \
  glyph/converter.c
libglyph_a_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS)
libglyph_a_CFLAGS =
libglyph_a_CXXFLAGS = $(AM_CXXFLAGS)

    EXTRA_LIBRARIES += \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_CRYPTO) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_UTIL) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_COMMON) \
  $(LIBGLYPH) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_CONSENSUS) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_SERVER) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_CLI) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_WALLET) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_ZMQ)

bitcoin_tx_LDADD = \
  $(LIBUNIVALUE) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_COMMON) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_UTIL) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_CONSENSUS) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_CRYPTO) \
  $(LIBGLYPH) \
  $(LIBSECP256K1)

bitcoind_LDADD = \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_SERVER) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_COMMON) \
  $(LIBUNIVALUE) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_UTIL) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_WALLET) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_ZMQ) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_CONSENSUS) \
  $(LIBBITCOIN_CRYPTO) \
  $(LIBLEVELDB) \
  $(LIBLEVELDB_SSE42) \
  $(LIBMEMENV) \
  $(LIBGLYPH) \
  $(LIBSECP256K1)
```

**I have tried at least 30 different compilation attempts where I reordered the compilation and/or renamed the library.**

Error:

```
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/joe/glyph/glyphCodebase/BitcoinUnlimited/src/secp256k1'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/joe/glyph/glyphCodebase/BitcoinUnlimited/src/secp256k1'
  CXXLD    bitcoind
libbitcoin_common.a(libbitcoin_common_a-key.o): In function `CKey::MakeNewKey()':
/home/joe/glyph/glyphCodebase/BitcoinUnlimited/src/key.cpp:25: undefined reference to `glp_gen_sk(glp_signing_key_st*)'
libbitcoin_common.a(libbitcoin_common_a-key.o): In function `CKey::GetPubKey() const':
/home/joe/glyph/glyphCodebase/BitcoinUnlimited/src/key.cpp:48: undefined reference to `glp_gen_pk(glp_public_key_st*, glp_signing_key_st)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:3556: recipe for target 'bitcoind' failed
make[2]: *** [bitcoind] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/joe/glyph/glyphCodebase/BitcoinUnlimited/src'
Makefile:9207: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/joe/glyph/glyphCodebase/BitcoinUnlimited/src'
Makefile:670: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

This error occurs despite libglyph.a being made and containing the functions. I have tried to add the library header and C files to common library with no luck either. I have rearranged the EXTRA_LIBRARIES section of the Makefile.am with no luck.

---

In order to simplify the problem, here is a really simple example that spits out the same error:

Adding 1 .h and 1 .cpp file to 1 already made library: libbitcoin_common
new files: `src/testFile.cpp src/testFile.h`

testFile.h:

```
void testFunction();
```

testFile.cpp

```
#include "testFile.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void testFunction() {
    printf("I am a test function");
}
```

added following lines to key.cpp:

```
#include "testFile.h"

void CKey::MakeNewKey()
{
    testFunction();
     ...
     ...
     ...
}
```

Then in src/Makefile.am

```
BITCOIN_CORE_H = \
testFile.h \
...
...
```

and the testFile to the common library, where key.cpp is, as mentioned by Pieter Wuille [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/bitcoin-core-makefile-addtions)

```
# common: shared between bitcoind, and bitcoin-qt and non-server tools
libbitcoin_common_a_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(BITCOIN_INCLUDES)
libbitcoin_common_a_CXXFLAGS = $(AM_CXXFLAGS) $(PIE_FLAGS)
libbitcoin_common_a_SOURCES = \
  amount.cpp \
  base58.cpp \
  chainparams.cpp \
  coins.cpp \
  compressor.cpp \
  core_read.cpp \
  core_write.cpp \
  keystore.cpp \
  netaddress.cpp \
  netbase.cpp \
  protocol.cpp \
  scheduler.cpp \
  script/sign.cpp \
  script/standard.cpp \
  key.cpp \
  testFile.cpp \
  $(BITCOIN_CORE_H)
```

The error:

```
libbitcoin_common.a(libbitcoin_common_a-key.o): In function 
`CKey::MakeNewKey()':
/home/joe/glyph/glyphCodebase/BitcoinUnlimited/src/key.cpp:23: undefined reference to `testFunction()
```

Please help me out with this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Adding a single source file and header is easier to do than adding a new library.

For a single source file, the file must come before any file that depends on it. So in your example, you should have

```
...
testFile.cpp \
key.cpp \
...
```

But you are really trying to add a new library. To do that, you need to add it to `bitcoind_LDADD` which is further down in `Makefile.am`. That way the linker knows to link it. For the linker, the dependencies need to be placed after the things that depend on it. So you can just adding `$(LIBGLYPH)` to the end of that list should work.

Comment: Wow thanks for such a quick response! I tried rearranging it and got the same error: 
libbitcoin_common.a(libbitcoin_common_a-key.o): In function `CKey::MakeNewKey()':
/home/joe/glyph/glyphCodebase/BitcoinUnlimited/src/key.cpp:23: undefined reference to `testFunction()'

Comment: I also added LIBGLYPH to bitcoind_LDADD and I tested adding it to the top and bottom and that also didn't worked

Comment: You might need to add it to `bitcoin_tx_LDADD` too. Can you update your question with the full output of the make command?

Comment: Also, did you remember to rerun `autogen.sh` and `configure` after modifying the makefile?

Comment: I updated the post with all of the changes I made. I left them out at first because I thought it would be too much info. It doesn't work with the addition to bitcoin_tx_LDADD. I also tried the sources and cxx section all with libbitcoin_glyph as the name and glyph_libbitcoin_glyph_a instead libglyph_a and that didn't work. I use ./autogen.sh and ./configure everytime I make a change. Here is the file if you want to see it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eB_EnxfSG1erRgDpDNgU_q-PzPQYs0hp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In `EXTRA_LIBRARIES`, have you tried putting libglyph before libbitcoin_common?

Comment: I figured it out! The issue is that the c++ compiler couldn't find where the function definitions were because they were in C. I wrapped the functions in extern "C" {   ...     }  but now I have an error: /usr/bin/ld: libglyph.a(libglyph_a-glp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
libglyph.a: error adding symbols: Bad value.
                                                       Which means that I have to use wildcard (like secp256k1 does).

Comment: Check out my answer

Answer (score 2):

There were 2 problems with the code:

1. you cannot compile c code with a c++ compiler without extern "C" in the header files of the C code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066279/using-c-libraries-for-c-programs
2. -fPIC might have to be used when compiling the C code (add it to the flags). I used liblibraryName_a_CFLAGS = -fPIC and liblibraryName_a_CXXFLAGS = -fPIC

For anyone that wants to see my makefile.am, go here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eB_EnxfSG1erRgDpDNgU_q-PzPQYs0hp/view?usp=sharing

Build systems are notoriously frustrating. If you have questions, leave a comment or ask me.